# Searching by Username field in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I would like to know how to search using the details in the username column of my Django admin without directly knowing the username.

I have objects in my admin and I want to be able to seach by the USERNAME_FIELD to access these objects about a given user.

At first I tried:

```
 search_fields = ('user__username', 'user__email',)
```

But that gave a FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field.

I'm now trying something I found in the Django documentation but it's giving me an error which says 'too many values to unpack'.

```
def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
     queryset, use_distinct = super(MyAdmin, self).get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
     queryset = self.model.objects.filter(get_user_model().USERNAME_FIELD)
     return queryset, use_distinct
```

The only solution I can think of is formatting a string which I'd rather not do since it's not very good code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by adding following in your admin.py file.

```
class WebUser(User):

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = "User"
        verbose_name_plural = "Users"


class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('user__username', 'user__email')

admin.site.register(WebUser, UserAdmin)
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. When I search by a username I get a FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field.

Comment: are you using your own User model or auth_user by django?

Comment: I'm using the User model

Comment: Thats what I am asking. Did you created your own User model? Django has its own user model. You can import it by
'from django.contrib.auth.models import User'.
Which user model you are using?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using my own user model and I've imported BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin

Comment: Remove this 
"search_fields = ('user__username', 'user__email',)"
with 
"search_fields = ('username', 'email',)" and tell me the result.

Comment: I get 'Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field.'